# How can I get rid of the error "Failed at the dandelion_pro@1.4.0 start script."?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dandelion

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dandelion_pro@1.4.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dandelion_pro@1.4.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-13T12_19_16_574Z-debug.log
```

This is how it appears on the terminal when attempting to start the project.

Comment: Well, have you checked the `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-13T12_19_16_574Z-debug.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in app folder?

Did you do `npm install`?

Can you provide us package.json?

Comment: What was output npm install? Can you post package.json?

Comment: Thank you salesh for helping. It resolved when I restarted the the project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved when I restarted and ran the project.